# Kivy Layout Issue

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a GUI using Kivy. However, I cannot resolve some formatting issues.
Here is a slimmed down version of my KV file:

```
BoxLayout:
    MainCanvas:
        size_hint: 1,1
        size: (root.width,root.height*.9)
        DoubleEllipseWidget:
        ActionBar:
            id: _action
            size_hint: 1,0.1
            size: (root.width,root.height*.1)
            pos_hint: {'bottom':1}
            ActionView:
                use_separator: True
                ActionPrevious:
                    title: 'Test App:'
                    with_previous: False
                ActionOverflow:
                    disabled: True
                ActionButton:
                    important: True
                    text: 'Button 1'
                    #on_release: some_function
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Button 2'
                    #on_release: some_function
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Button 3'
                    #on_release: some_function


<DoubleEllipseWidget>
    size: [200, 200]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Ellipse
            size: [198, 198]
            pos: [600-200-100, 800-200-100]
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Ellipse
            size: [200, 200]
            pos: [600-200-100, 800-200-100]
    TextInput:
        on_parent:self.focus = True
        text: 'center of circle'
        background_color: (0,0,0,0)
        foreground_color: (0,0,0,1)
```

What I am trying to get to is very easily explained.

Essentially, there should be a menu bar running horizontally along the screen window (10% of total height and 100% of width). I believe I have done this.

The remaining 95% height should be the main canvas - I believe I have also done this.

The final part is getting a particular widget to be placed into the center of the main canvas. This is where I am stuck and would appreciate some help.

The widget I need to center is made up of two circles (one centered on top of the other, with one being slightly smaller than the other). Then, on top of the top-most circle should be a TextInput.

Comment: I meant the remaining 90% rather than 95%.

Comment: What is a `MainCanvas`?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. It's simply an area where I shall be dynamically adding different widgets. I am OK with this. However, the 'DoubleEllipseWidget' should remain static in the center and it's this I am struggling with.

Comment: In order for us to see what is happening, we need a [mcve]. At least show us the class definitions for `MainCanvas` and `DoubleEllipseWidget`.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I thought this is what I had done. For those two classes its around 300 lines of code. I am brand new to to Kivy so that are likely non-optimal and verbose but in any case, I felt simplifying the problem as I have done was best. I will see if I can simplify the python in a logical manner and if I can I shall amend the post. Thanks for looking anyway.

Comment: Since you are only asking about the layout, any methods in those two classes that don't affect layout are not important. If those classes extend standard Kivy classes, you might try just replacing your classes with their base classes (in the posted `kv`) to see if you still get the same layout problem.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the advice from this community, I stripped all of the logic back until I was left with just the basics (class definitions and layout), and was still having issues.

However, I have now learnt that what I assumed was a layout issue was likely not. A Kivy bug report last commented on in Nov 2018 (TextInput focus problem #3863), suggests there are unexplained instances where textinputs can lose focus. Below is the suggested workaround which also worked for me. Thanks for those that tried to help me.

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    Builder.load_string('''
    <Base>:
    Button:
        text: 'Press for Popup'
        on_press: root.edit_text()

    <TextInputX>
    id: texter
    keyboard_mode: 'managed'
    is_focusable: True
    focus: True
    keyboard_on_key_down:
        texter.show_keyboard()
''')


class Base(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def edit_text(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()
        content = TextInputX()
        # content.focus = True
        popup = Popup(content=content)
        popup.open()


class TextInputX(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputX, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.focus = True


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Base()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```